# Creating UIImage from JPEG NSData is slow on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

This operation takes 700 ms on iPhone 5 running iOS 7.1.2.

```
UIImage(data: data)
```

`data` is NSData containing JPEG image, 400x300px 90K.

- It slows down the UI even if run in a separate thread.
- Only happens for JPEGs, PNGs are fine.
- Only happens during the first call.
- Only happens on iOS 7.1.2. iOS 8 in simulator is fine.

How can I make it load faster or it least not block the UI?

Demo app is here: https://github.com/exchangegroup/demo-image-loader-benchmark-swift

### Update

This slowdown only happens when I start the app on the device **from Xcode**. When started from the device itself it runs much faster, at about 20ms. First run is still much slower than subsequent runs, which are about 1ms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will highly depend on the size of your images being loaded, what their original compression was, etc.

In general, you should **NEVER** base performance assumptions off of debug builds from Xcode, and that goes **TRIPLE** if you've got the debugger attached. If you want to see how fast something really is, you want to build and install to the device using the Release profile that comes with your project, and run the build without the debugger attached. Release builds are generally at least 1 order of magnitude faster, assuming you've followed standard procedures like wrapping NSLog so it doesn't spit out logs to the console for Release builds.

Comment: Wow thanks, this is very useful information! Please forgive my ignorance, in order to make a release build and run it on device, do I edit scheme and select "Release" build configuration?